# Memory leak with UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

When presenting a view controller modally, setting the transition style appears to create a memory leak. When the third line below isn't commented out, the new view controller is unresponsive, the memory indicator in XCode's Debug Navigator steadily climbs, and eventually the app crashes. When the line is commented out, it works just fine.

```
- (IBAction)settingsPressed:(id)sender {
    SettingsPopupViewController *pvc=[[SettingsPopupViewController alloc] init];
    pvc.partyPlanName=[self partyPlanName];
    //pvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    pvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    pvc.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It seems odd that something like a transition style would cause this, so my guess is that the longer transition time of UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal may be leading to issues in SettingsPopupViewController. That said, commenting out all the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear code in that object didn't make any difference. Are there any known issues with this transition style? Thanks for reading.

UPDATE:
Looking at the issue in Instruments shows that a row with Category "Malloc 272 Bytes" is what's steadily increasing when the transition line is uncommented.

Comment: `^(void){}`???? Just say `nil`... Okay, more seriously - use Instruments! It will tell you exactly where all the memory is going and why. No need to ask, no need to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was specific to iOS8 and was caused by resizing the modal view in viewWillLayoutSubviews. By adding an iOS version check, the problem was fixed:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8.0){
        self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 366, 553);
    }
}
```

To set the modal view controller's size on iOS8 devices, I used the following code from the calling object (just before presentViewController is called):

```
modalViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(366, 553);
```